# スマートコントラクトへのトークン追加について

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity

トークンを追加するメソッドを作りました
トランザクションはブロックに書き込まれるのですが、トークンが増えません

処理前のトークンの確認

```
truffle(rpc)> tk.balances(web3.eth.accounts[0])
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 4, c: [ 10010 ] }

truffle(rpc)> cc.balances(web3.eth.accounts[1])
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

以下solidity抜粋

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";

address public minter;
uint256 public totalSupply;

constructor(uint initialSupply) public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply;
    balances[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    minter = msg.sender;
}

function chargeTK(uint256 _value) public {
    balances[minter] = balances[minter].add(_value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_value);
}
```

以下python抜粋

```
W3.personal.unlockAccount(ADDRESS_0, ADDRESS_0_PWD)
res = contract_instance.functions.transfer(W3.eth.accounts[1], 10).transact({'from': ADDRESS_0, 'gas': 50000})
W3.personal.lockAccount(ADDRESS_0)
res_dict = W3.eth.getTransaction(W3.toHex(res))
while str(res_dict['blockNumber']) == 'None':
    time.sleep(5)
    res_dict = W3.eth.getTransaction(W3.toHex(res))

print('blockNumber:', str(res_dict['blockNumber']))
```

以下実行結果

```
blockNumber: 30317
```

処理後のトークンの確認

```
truffle(rpc)> tk.balances(web3.eth.accounts[0])
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 4, c: [ 10010 ] }

truffle(rpc)> cc.balances(web3.eth.accounts[1])
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

Ether Block Explorerをインストールして確認したところ、トランザクションの確認(ガス消費)はできましたがトークンの動きがわかる情報がどこかわかりませんでした

`res = contract_instance.functions.transfer(W3.eth.accounts[1],　10).transact({'from': ADDRESS_0, 'gas': 50000})`の箇所に問題があるのであればエラーとになりそうですが、どこに問題があるか確認すべき箇所わかりますでしょうか?

pythonでの実行は置いておき、
gethでの送金を試した結果を追加します

```
> var tk_abi = [...]
> var tk_con = web3.eth.contract(tk_abi)
> var tk = tk_con.at("0x...")

> tk.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0])
10010

> eth.defaultAccount=eth.accounts[0]
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
> tk.transfer.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[1], 10)

> tk.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0])
10010

> tk.balanceOf(eth.accounts[1])
0
```

やはりトークン送金できていませんでした

Answer (score 0, accepted):

色々試しているうちに自己解決しました

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";

    address public minter;
    // uint256 public totalSupply;

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public {
        totalSupply_ = initialSupply;  // mod
        balances[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
```

明確になっていないのですが、
`totalSuplay`の変数宣言を削除
質問にて記載が漏れていましたが、`balances`のマッピング宣言を削除
あたりで、動くようになりました